# Command "hadoop fs -ls ." does not work

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I think I have installed hadoop correctly. If I do `jps` I can see the namenode and datanode, no problem.

When I type `hadoop fs -ls .` I get the error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/db/hadoop-2.4.1/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/08/08 12:42:44 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: '.': No such file or directory
```

When I type `hadoop dfs -ls .` I get the error:

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/db/hadoop-2.4.1/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/08/08 12:43:27 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: '.': No such file or directory
```

And when I type `hadoop hdfs -ls .` I get the error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class hdfs`

This is regardless of whether I put '.' or '/' or whatever directory I'm in.

What does this all mean? How can I get normal, expected output? What am I missing?

Comment: export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"

Add these two lines in .bashrc and reopen your terminal and try restarting hadoop.

Comment: did you restart hadoop?

Comment: oh... no I'll do that. I realised it took away the warning anyway which is great! I'll restart now

Comment: try `hadoop dfs -ls /`

Comment: ok if I try 'hadoop dfs -ls /' i get the following:
`DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

14/08/08 12:59:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
`

Comment: So then I tried: hadoop hdfs -ls / and got
`Error: Could not find or load main class hdfs`

Comment: Dont mind about that warning. Is it working?

Comment: It's not working yet :(

Comment: are there any files in HDFS? why don't check in UI http:/localhost/50070

Comment: no... how do I put one in? Where does it go?

Comment: I tried the put command.. I get exactly the same errors.

Comment: use `hadoop dfs` everytime dont use `hdfs`

Comment: even though I'm told it's deprecated?

Comment: join me in chat [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58952/discussion-between-y-prithvi-and-dee)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
hdfs dfs -ls ...
```

I dont think there is such a thing as `hadoop hdfs`

Comment: makes no difference in the output for me! I actually found hadoop does work in the end :)

Answer (score -2):

use the command as follows

```
bin/hadoop fs -ls /
```