# Unknown host error when listing with hadoop fs -ls /

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and trying to install Hadoop on multinode cluster on ubuntu 14.04-Server on VM. All goes well until I try to list the files within HDFS using `hadoop fs -ls /`

I keep getting an error:

> ls: unknown host: Hadoop-Master.

Initially I thought I made some mistake in assigning the hostname but cross-checked with `/etc/hosts` and `/etc./hostname`. Hostname is listed correctly as Hadoop-Master. Removed hostname altogether. Only ip address remaining.

[Another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201731/command-hadoop-fs-ls-does-not-work) suggested to add two lines to `.bashrc`:

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native 
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib

I tried doing that but still getting the same error.
Please find the relevant steps below along with edits based on information asked.

- Check IP address of the master with ifconfig
- Add to the /etc/hosts and edit the /etc/hostname to add the host name.
- Add the relevant details to masters and slaves.

**.bashrc File**

```
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/Hive

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

**Java path**
**export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle'**

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs:Hadoop-Master:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hadoop-env.sh**

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle'
```

Edit mapred-site.xml to include the hostname and change the value to no. of nodes present. 
**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Edit hdfs-site.xml, changed the value to no. of data nodes present.​
**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**whoami**
simplilearn

**/etc/hosts**
localhost 127.0.0.1
Hadoop-Master 192.168.207.132
Hadoop-Slave  192.168.207.140

**/etc/hostname**
Hadoop-Master

Comment: Try removing `-` from `Hadoop-Master` in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I did that, but same error: 
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
ls: Unknown host: Hadoop-Master...

Comment: Could you post the error now for `hadoop fs -ls /`?

Comment: No change. 
ls: Unknown host: Hadoop-Master.

Comment: @RajeshN Well, there is no change at all. 

"$HADOOP_HOME is deprecated. ls: Unknown host: Hadoop-Master"

Comment: What does `whoami` results(in terminal)? Also could you post your `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` in your question?

Comment: @RajeshN updated the question with the whoami & host and hostnames!

Answer (score 0):

**Changes to be made:**

**1. /etc/hosts** file:

Change `Hadoop-Master` to `HadoopMaster`

**2. /etc/hostname** file:

Change `Hadoop-Master` to `HadoopMaster`

**3. core-site.xml**:

Change this

> hdfs:Hadoop-Master:9001

to this

```
hdfs://HadoopMaster:9001
```

**NOTE:** Change **Hadoop-Master** to **HadoopMaster** in all nodes pointing to your IP. Change **slaves** and **master** files too.